# HTML : Page load every 5 secs and display countdown like 5,4,3,2,1 and then reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, reload

Can someone please help me on html reload page for every 5 secs and also i need to have something like below.

In my page, i have "refresh" link, once i click that refresh link, refresh should disappear and it should start showing countdown as 5,4,3,2,1 etc and then it has to reload the same page again, can you please help me.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and how it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
            var counter = 5;
            var myCounter = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);

            function myFunction() {
              if (counter > 0) {
                document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = counter;
                counter--;
              } else {
                clearInterval(myCounter);
                document.location.reload(true)
              }

            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9423bvp1/

Comment: You can use button to start this counter but after reload it won't visible again. you should set button's visibility from server side code. That's my opinion. Good luck.